# Chrome extension load one of the two extensions by user country

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have two chrome extensions, one for Asia region and one for rest regions. If in case user installs both the extension, I am checking the user's location and if the user location is within Asia, I want to stop the other extension and let the user proceed with Asia extension and vice versa.

I have used externally_connectable in my manifest json for both extensions but need the best possible way to execute that.

Below is my manifest foir Asia extension

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://www.abcd.com/*"],
    "ids":["hkjgcgefggapaedjfmoeaijegegmbiak"]
}
```

This one for other Extension

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://www.efgh.com/*"],
    "ids":["hfennmphapjcpkfkanbhlfioimophbfi"]
}
```

I am making a call from my content script and checking if the extension exist and if yes Ill check the user location and continue with any one of that. But the issue is if both extension start execution then the process will be initiated from both ends. I want to check it in any one of that extension to complete the detection. Please provide me suitable solution for the same.

Comment: Why two extensions?

Comment: @StephanBijzitter coz it have different logic as per two different locations also its a kind of child extension

Comment: Sounds like job for [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). You have to determine if both extensions are there before your code executes.

Comment: @LonnieBest I am able to determine if extension exist but dont know how to control the execution. I mean if one has already initiated the logic to check if other is present then it should not b carried out by both parallely

Comment: With promises you could not allow either to execute until AFTER you've determined if either or both exists.

Comment: @LonnieBest didn't get you... can ypu plz explain a bit more clear...

Comment: At first couldn't you just prevent either plugin from being used until you've fully determined which ones they have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133361/discussion-between-sandeep-j-patel-and-lonnie-best).

Comment: @LonnieBest, There is nothing special about Promises which allows you to accomplish this vs. other methods of doing so. Promises are just a way to specify asynchronous operation using a particular set of semantics. While they can make code look cleaner, depending on the code, there is nothing inherent in them that can not be accomplished using other semantics.